# Compare pointers by type?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, types

How could I compare two pointers to see if they are of the same type?

Say I have...

```
int * a;
char * b;
```

I want to know whether or not these two pointers differ in type.

Details:

I'm working on a lookup table (implemented as a 2D void pointer array) to store pointers to structs of various types. I want to use one insert function that compares the pointer type given to the types stored in the first row of the table. If they match I want to add the pointer to the table in that column.

Basically I want to be able to store each incoming type into its own column.

[image]

Alternative methods of accomplishing this are welcomed.

Comment: Don't you already know that?

Comment: Still a little confusing... but I think I get it now

Comment: Couldn't you do this with operator overloading?  For example, you could have three insert functions:
  insert(int key, A*);
  insert(int key, B*);
  insert(int key, C*);

Comment: I considered that, but since there are over 50 types I didn't want to have to write 50+ overloaded methods. In most cases I only care about 3-4 of them, if there was a way to "ignore" the other types this would work well for my use case.

Comment: Could you ignore the other types with a template member function that did nothing, and then only overload the 3-4 that you care about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, since you know the types before hand, it doesn't make much sense to check. You can just proceed knowing that they are different types.

However, assuming that perhaps the types may be dependent on some compile-time properties like template arguments, you could use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
std::is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value
```

This will be `true` if they are the same type and `false` otherwise.

Comment: IIRC, this is a C++11 thing, so check for compiler support.

Comment: Good answer. 1 thing I don't get is when C++ started shielding us from the facts? Where does `std::is_same` get its information from?

Comment: @MrUniverse: There's no magic behind `is_same`; it's just partially specialised to contain `value = true` if both template arguments are the same, and `value = false` otherwise. You could easily implement it yourself if you wanted.